# How can I tell whether sample size is inadequate or not?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, sampling

I am given sample size of 15322 students and our research topic is to find out a relationship between students academic performance and participation in sports team.

The question asks " do you think the sample size is adequate for our purpose?"

It seems like its very subjective question.

I don't know whether it is adequate or not.

Anybody has better ideas?

Comment: In this form, it is indeed subjective. At the very least, one would need information about what kind of relationships are to be considered, and how strong an effect would be considered "interesting" or "expected".

Comment: If this is a problem from a course or textbook, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the effect size, correlation between predictors, power, etc.

Let's say you're going to do a linear regression (grade as a function of playing on sports teams and other stuff).  The main variable of interest is the indicator for "plays on sports teams".

Roughly, the required sample size for this analysis assuming 80% power and 5% fpr is

$$ n = \dfrac{8\sigma^2_y}{(\beta \sigma_x)^2(1-\rho^2)}$$

Where

- $\sigma_y$ is the standard deviation of the outcome (grades) conditioned on covariates
- $\beta$ is the effect of being on a sports team
- $\sigma_x$ is the standard deviation of the binary predictor for being on a sports team
- $(1-\rho^2)$ is the variance inflation factor.

We can re-arrange this to yield a formula for power as a function of sample size and the rest

$$ \gamma=1-\Phi\left[z_{1-\alpha / 2}-\left|\beta_{j}^{a}\right| \sigma_{x_{j}} \sqrt{n\left(1-\rho_{j}^{2}\right)} / \sigma_{y | \mathbf{x}}\right] $$

With $n=15000$ you would need a very large standard deviation in the outcome or a very small effect to have small power.  Feel free to take these and play with them.  I understand this may not be relevant anymore but thought I would answer for posterity.